# Sharedpreferences are not saving (anymore)

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I've been working with SharedPreferences in my application for a long time but lately it doesn't seem to save anymore. I'm not sure if it's the case for all preferences, but I know at least it is for rememberLogin and tutorialMode.
Below are some pieces of code where I use these preferences.

rememberLogin (set):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref2 = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.rememberLogin), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor2 = sharedPref2.edit();
editor2.putBoolean(getString(R.string.rememberLogin), ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbRemember)).isChecked());
editor2.apply();
```

rememberLogin (get):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref3 = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.rememberLogin), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean rememberLogin = sharedPref3.getBoolean(getString(R.string.rememberLogin), true);
```

tutorialMode (set):

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.tutorialMode), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putBoolean(getString(R.string.tutorialMode), false);
editor.apply();
```

tutorialMode (get):

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.tutorialMode), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Intent intent;
if (sharedPref.getBoolean(getString(R.string.tutorialMode), true)) {
    intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
} else {
    intent = new Intent(LoadActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Part of strings.xml (Where I keep my SharedPreferences):

```
<!-- Shared Preferences -->
<string name="apiKey" translatable="false" />
<string name="expirationTime" translatable="false">7</string>
<string name="rememberLogin" translatable="false">true</string>
<string name="user_id" translatable="false">0</string>
<string name="flashMode" translatable="false">off</string>
<string name="flashMode2" translatable="false">off</string>
<string name="connType" translatable="false">0</string>
<string name="notified" translatable="false">false</string>
<string name="tutorialMode" translatable="false">true</string>
```

When I make changes (in the set) they seem to be the same as before (in the get).

Comment: `not working ` means nothing specific really

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Good point, I've edited my post, the specific problem I'm having is that the preferences don't seem to get saved anymore

Comment: this is a side note, why you are creating several Shared Preference files and in each file 1 key? you have to create 1 file, and save all keys inside, i am talking about using different names when calling `getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.tutorialMode)....`

Comment: @Yazan As far as I know it is all in 1 file, namely the strings.xml file (I keep all my SharedPreferences here), I have made an edit where I show that

Comment: `getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode)` is the name and mode of the main prefs file, where keys with different names are stored,-you can call `getString(), getBoolean()...` with different names (keys) - what you are doing is getting a different Preferences file when you pass different name each time.

Comment: @Yazan I thought the String in getSharedPreferences should be the same as the String in getString or getBoolean.

Comment: nop, its the file name, and thats leads us to the fact that different files with same name is being created (or at least try-to-create) -based on your strings.xml segmant- "tutorialMode" and "rememberLogin" both **files** will be named `true `which is not possible to have 2 files with same name in same path, so i suggest you use a hardcoded name in `getSharedPreferences()` ex, `getSharedPreferences("myAppPrefs",PRIVATE)` and test the code again

Comment: @Yazan I think I know what I did wrong, I thought I had to use the strings in such a way that the value would be the default value for that preference, that's why multiple are on true, and those seem to interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem:

I thought that I needed to put the default value of the preferences as value in the strings.xml file, but that's not the case. So my file was something like this:

```
<!-- Shared Preferences -->
<string name="apiKey" translatable="false" />
<string name="expirationTime" translatable="false">7</string>
<string name="rememberLogin" translatable="false">true</string>
<string name="user_id" translatable="false">0</string>
<string name="flashMode" translatable="false">off</string>
<string name="flashMode2" translatable="false">off</string>
<string name="connType" translatable="false">0</string>
<string name="notified" translatable="false">false</string>
<string name="tutorialMode" translatable="false">true</string>
```

While it should be something like this:

```
<!-- Shared Preferences -->
<string name="apiKey" translatable="false">apiKey</string>
<string name="expirationTime" translatable="false">experationTime</string>
<string name="rememberLogin" translatable="false">rememberLogin</string>
<string name="user_id" translatable="false">user_id</string>
<string name="flashMode" translatable="false">flashMode</string>
<string name="flashMode2" translatable="false">flashMode2</string>
<string name="connType" translatable="false">connType</string>
<string name="notified" translatable="false">notified</string>
<string name="tutorialMode" translatable="false">tutorialMode</string>
```

Also, as Yavan pointed out, I had different file names for each of my preferences, this was because I thought that the name in the getSharedPreferencesMethod referred to the name of the preference instead of the name of the file, so I've changed that too now.